# How to set a search bar not in a tool bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create such layout:

[image]

I'm struglying to understand how to add this search bar under the tool bar. All of the exampels I saw are setting the search bar in the tool bar. How can I set such search bar?

Comment: Just use an EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SearchView` in `AppBarLayout`:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        app:title="Toolbar"
        app:titleTextColor="#fff" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:queryHint="Search"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:background="@drawable/background"/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**background.xml**

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#fff" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

[image: 1]